# SQL Date intelligence: filtering data by seconds ran from last known valid result

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, calculated-columns, calculation

Help! We're trying to create a new column (Is Valid?) to reproduce the logic below.

It is a binary result that:

- it is 1 if it is the first known value of an ID
- it is 1 if it is 3 seconds or later than the previous "1" of that ID

**Note 1**: this is not the difference in seconds from the previous record

- It is 0 if it is less than 3 seconds than the previous "1" of that ID

**Note 2**: there are many IDs in the data set

**Note 3**: original dataset has ID and Date

Attached a PoC of the data and the expected result.

[image: PoC dataset image]

[image: PoC dataset spreadsheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to do this using a recursive CTE, which is quite expensive:

```
with tt as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by time) as seqnum
      from t
     ),     
     recursive cte as (
      select t.*, time as grp_start
      from tt
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select tt.*,
             (case when tt.time < cte.grp_start + interval '3 second'
                   then tt.time
                   else tt.grp_start
               end)
      from cte join
           tt
           on tt.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )
select cte.*,
       (case when grp_start = lag(grp_start) over (partition by id order by time)
             then 0 else 1
        end) as isValid
from cte;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon! Do you know a way to overcome Amazon Redshift limitation on recursive CTE?

Comment: @mfulvio . . . I don't think you can do this in Redshift.